# terraform - mounting a directory in yaml

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

i am managing instances on goole cloud platform and deploying the docker image into GCP by using terraform script. The problem that I have now with the Terraform script is mounting a host directory into a docker container when docker image is started.

If I can manually run a docker command, i can do something like this.

```
docker run -v <host_dir>:<container_local_path> -it <image_id>
```

But I need to configure the mount directory in the Terraform Yaml. This is my Terraform YAML file.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: MyDocker
      image: "docker_image_name"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
```

I have a directory (/www/project/data) in the host machine. This directory needs to be mounted into the docker container.

Does anybody know how to mount this directory into this yaml file?

Or any workaround is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an annswer. please make sure 'dataDir' name has to match between 'volumeMounts and volumes'.

```
      volumeMounts:
       - name: 'dataDir'
         mountPath: '/data/'
  volumes:
  - name: 'dataDir'
    hostPath:
      path: '/tmp/logs'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are loading Docker images into a Container based Compute Engine.  My recommendation is to determine your recipe for creating your GCE image and mounting your disk manually using the GCP console.  The following will give guidance on that task.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#mounting_a_host_directory_as_a_data_volume

Once you are able to achieve your desired GCP environment by hand, there appears to be a recipe for translating this into a Terraform script as documented here:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1022

The high level recipe seems to be the recognition that the configuration of docker commands and specification is found in Metadata of the Compute Engine configuration.  We can find the desired metadata by running the command manually and looking at the REST request that would achieve that.  Once we know the metadata, we can transcribe that into the equivalent settings in the terraform script to be added by Terraform.